# android/java - looking for an efficient concurrent cyclic queue

Tags: java, android, queue, cyclic

does anyone know of an (open source) implementation of a bounded concrrent cyclic queue , or an available API class built into android/java ?

the concurrent (not synchronized or lock based) operations i need for this collection are at least enqueue and dequeue , but enqueue can also be enough .

for those who are not sure about the collection i need , here's some more info:

- bounded - has max number of items that can be in it .
- concurrent - allows multiple threads to run operations efficiently without any kind of locking. that's the opposite of synchronized solutions , which only allows a single thread to run operations.
- cyclic - if we put items into a filled collection , the new item will replace the oldest item.

please help

Comment: sounds like you should just copy `ArrayBlockingQueue.java` (it's available in the framework source) and change the `#offer(T)` and `#put(T)` methods to dequeue the last item - and presto - instant bounded queue that expels the last item.

Comment: @Jens - ArrayBlockingQueue doesn't permit concurrent access by multiple threads, judging by the source.

Comment: correct .not only that , but it isn't cyclic as well:  if you try to put an item into a filled queue , it will wait on it till it's not filled , and the opposite - if you try to get an item from an empty queue , it will wait on it till it's not empty .

Comment: ArrayBlockingQueue `#offer(T)` is non-blocking, just as `#poll()` - the blocking versions are `#put(T)` and `#take()` respectively - so *yeah*, they're used when you need concurrent non-blocking poll & offer.. @androiddeveloper: Yes, that's why you'd have to copy & modify the source to dequeue when the queue is full.

Comment: "concurrent - allows multiple threads to run operations efficiently without any kind of locking" -- by definition, this is impossible.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I'm guessing he meant "blocking".

Comment: both of us are correct - i meant non-blocking algorithm , so it is lock free and doesn't use any locks (excluding the hardware features) .those terms are about the same: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm . basically, you can use a hardware solution like CAS in order to avoid using locks , but it's very hard to design a correct algorithm . you can read more about it on many websites , such as this: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~multi/?p=slides .

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds very much like [disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/), but it's an external library, not built in. As far as I know, there is no built-in ring buffer data structure in Java standard library.

Comment: correct. it does look similar . do you think it's exactly what i need? do they have a sample code of usage? if so , i will give you a V . :)

Comment: There is a code sample in point 4.7 of the [technical description document](http://disruptor.googlecode.com/files/Disruptor-1.0.pdf) [PDF] as well as [in the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/wiki/CodeExampleDisruptor2x). Whether disruptor is exactly what you need, only you can tell :)

Comment: the sample code doesn't look any similar to what a queue really is . also, i'm not sure what is the purpose of the BatchHandler ,batchConsumer , ConsumerBarrier , and ProducerBarrier. kindly show  some code that implements the enqueue & dequeue methods which use this library?